# Water equivalent of calorimeter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am trying to solve numerical problem based on calorimetry. The water equivalent of a calorimeter is given in grams. But how is it possible as

w= mc and unit of m*c is Cal/°C.

- where w= water equivalent
- m= mass of the water
- c= specific heat of water

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what quantity you are trying to compute and what you kean by equivalent water

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of water equivalent is incorrect.

An object with a mass $m$, made of a substance with specific heat $C$, has a water equivalent $w$:

$$w= \frac{m \times C}{C_w} $$where $C_w$ is the specific heat of water, in the same units as $C$.

Thus, $w$ will have the same units as $m$.

Comment: Oh that's true. Actually our teacher didn't make it so clear that is why I had the doubt. Thank you so much. I will ask you if i had any doubt in comment section..