# Why does thermal capacity and water equivalent have different units?

Tags: thermodynamics

Specific heat units are

> J/Kg-K

Thermal capacity of a body is

> mC, m is mass and C is specific heat. Units are J/K

Since specific heat is multiplied by mass, units of thermal capacity can be interpreted as units Kg in units of C gets cancelled with Kg in units of mass. So, units of thermal capacity are J/K.

But considering formula for water equivalent

> W = mC, m is mass and C is specific heat.

If both the thermal capacity and water equivalent are equal to mC, Why units of water equivalent are Kg?

Comment: Where is the term water equivalent used? This is unclear without a reference.

Comment: Your formula for water equivalent is wrong. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412177/water-equivalent-of-calorimeter

Comment: Okay, my reference was not clear. Thanks for the link.